How can I let maven deploy to snapshot repo only classifier zip package (int) instead of 2 classifiers zip packages (dev and int)?
Using mvn clean deploy -Pint command, 2 zip files are systematically pushed to nexus snapshot repository: myapp-0.0.1-timestamp-2-dev.zip and myapp-0.0.1-timestamp-2-int.zip.However, I aim to push only package with -int when I choose -Pint profile, and package with -dev when I choose -Pdev profile.Bellow how assembly plugin is configured with profiles:


<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Create dev resources</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>myapp-${project.version}</finalName>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/profile_dev.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>int</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Create int resources</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>myapp-${project.version}</finalName>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/profile_int.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>



Please let me know if you'd like that I share profile_dev.xml and profile_int.xml descriptors.I'm using maven 3.6.3 version.Thank you in advance for your help.

Please post the full pom file... also describe all versions of plugins etc. you are using? The descriptors would also be helpful..
